# Get dictionary in python to store primitive type objects (memory location) instead of the value of those objects?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to store attributes of an object in a dictionary so I can change those attributes later. The problem is that these attributes are booleans, so when I put them in a dictionary it stores the boolean value, not the attribute variable.

I.e.

```
    location_dict = {
    'dorm_common':newnom.dorm_common,
    'cafeteria':newnom.cafeteria,
    'comp_room':newnom.comp_room}
```

I want to iterate through the dict and change newnom.comp_room = True. The problem is that the dictionary is storing the default value of newnom.comp_room, which is None, so I can't set newnom.comp_room.

I can think of plenty of ways to get around this such as making newnom.comp_room "newnom.comp_room" and using exec(v+'True'), or going into

```
    (newnom.__dict__()[k] = True)
```

but I was wondering if there was another way to override this default behavior in a python dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't something special about dictionaries. It's intrinsic to the Python programming language as a whole. You want either pass-by-reference or mutable booleans (and in any case you should review your understanding of Python's semantics and its implementation, you sound like you may be confusing some things), but Python doesn't support that. And you can't change that, and if you could, you'd face several can's worth of worms.

Change your design such that (in increasing order of obscurity)...

- you only store the object, and access/change the various attributes through other means (e.g. with `getattr`/`setattr`, or a dedicated method with validation to limit dynamicness creep and accidents - might even make `newnom` ). I really recommend this. It's by far the simplest and least surprising approach.
- you can go from the dict value to the object and change the attribute directly (e.g. store a (object, attribute name) tuple: `(newnom, 'dorm_common')`).
- `location_dict` is not really a dict but an object supporting some dictionary operations and routed them to manipulation of `newnom`. (I would only recommend such hackery if you have a ton of legacy code that requires an external dictionary).

Answer (score 0):

What you could do it try using a proxy object that contains the value that you want to modify:

```
class MutableProxy(object):
    __slots__ = "value"
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def get(self):
        return self.value

    def set(self, value):
        self.value = value
```

You can then use the `get()` and `set()` functions to set the actual values, something like:

```
>>> var_1 = MutableProxy(100)
>>> var_1.get()
100
>>> d = { "var_1" : var_1 }
>>> d["var_1"].set(600)
>>> var_1.get()
600
```

The major disadvantage of this is that the proxy object will take noticeably more memory than the raw object, but that might be an appropriate trade-off.